# try/with in an asyncResult block, in F#?

Tags: f#

How is the try / finally working in an asyncResult block:

```
let loadAndParseTrades ticker (dayDate: DateTime) : Async<Result<TradeData list, ExchangeError>> =
    asyncResult {
        try
            // wait for loading semaphore
            loadingSemaphores.WaitOne() |> ignore
        
            // load the data
            let date  = dayDate.Floor (TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
            let func  = client.GetAsync(buildTradesRequest ticker date) |> Async.AwaitTask
            let! data = getDataAsync func

            // parse it and return it                
            return Parser.parseTrades ticker data []
        
        finally
            loadingSemaphores.Release() |> ignore
    }
```

I have this function loading a large zip file and parsing it.

I would like to catch exceptions here and return an Error:

```
try
    try
        // wait for loading semaphore
        loadingSemaphores.WaitOne() |> ignore
    
        // load the data
        let date  = dayDate.Floor (TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
        let func  = client.GetAsync(buildTradesRequest ticker date) |> Async.AwaitTask
        let! data = getDataAsync func

        // parse it and return it                
        return Parser.parseTrades ticker data []

    with ex ->
        let err = Error (ExchangeError.ServiceException ex)  // <- Result<'a,ExchangeError>
        AsyncResult.returnError err             
    
finally
    loadingSemaphores.Release() |> ignore
```

but then this doesn't seem to be possible here:

```
  Loader.fs(75, 21): [FS0193] Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    'Async<Result<unit,'a>>'    
is not compatible with type
    'Async<Result<TradeData list,ExchangeError>>'
```

what am I missing here?

---

Edit:

Added a sample that everyone can compile

```
let testSomethingAsync x =
    async {
        if x % 2 = 0 then
            return Ok x
        else
            return Error "oh, no!"
    }        

let doSomethingAsync x =
    asyncResult {
        try    
            let! a = testSomethingAsync x
            return a * 2
        with ex ->

            // none of these compile
            // AsyncResult.returnError "no no no"            
            // Error (AsyncResult.returnError "no no no")             
            // return (AsyncResult.returnError "no no no")
            // return (Error (AsyncResult.returnError "no no no"))
```

since:

> let returnError x = Error x |> Async.singleton

we can assume that the lines:

```
Error (AsyncResult.returnError "no no no")             
return (Error (AsyncResult.returnError "no no no"
```

will not compile for sure.

The line:

```
AsyncResult.returnError "no no no"
```

will fail to compile with:

```
Type constraint mismatch. The type 'Async<Result<unit,'a>>' is not compatible with type 'Async<Result<int,string>>'
```

And the line:

```
return (AsyncResult.returnError "no no no")
```

will fail to compile with:

```
This expression was expected to have type 'int' but here has type 'Async<Result<'a,'b>>'
```

I'm a bit lost here...

Comment: Where is `AsyncResult.returnError` defined?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, it's here: https://github.com/demystifyfp/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling/blob/2ad6c0a54e2a402703d99b748b3c8ad7ada849c6/src/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling/AsyncResult.fs part of FSToolkit

Comment: Aren't you just missing a return from the catch? `return AsyncResult.returnError err`

Comment: @TomMoers no, I’ve tried that as well

Comment: From that definition, it looks like it expects an error as parameter, but you're giving it a `Result<_, _>`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin just returning my own type (ExchangeError...) still won't compile. I'll build a small sample without custom types and post it here.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, I've edited the question and added a reproducible sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
let doSomethingAsync x =
    asyncResult {
        try    
            let! a = testSomethingAsync x
            return a * 2
        with ex ->
            return! AsyncResult.error "no no no"
    }
```